# Terminology for describing lack of agreement between a clause and subject

Tags: grammaticality

First question, and apologies if I word it awkwardly.

Someone posted a chart of emotions. At the top were the words, "As a writer, this has proved to be a truly valuable chart." Here's the link: https://www.facebook.com/writerscircle/photos/a.469562786290.301523.110046421290/10153994207441291/?type=3&theater

Now, I know that's wrong. The chart's not a writer. But I'm flailing about for the correct terms to describe WHY it's wrong. Lack of agreement between a prepositional phrase and sentence subject? Or...?

Could someone supply the technical terms for what's wrong with that sentence?

Thanks in advance.

Cyn

Answer (score 2):

There are several terms that are used for the problem exemplified in your sentence. The *Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar* (p251) calls such constructions *misrelated*, and defines them as follows:

> Not attached grammatically to the word or phrase intended by the
>   meaning, either joined to the wrong word or phrase, or completely
>   unattached.
>
> ...
>
> Although terms such as *misrelated*, *dangling*, *hanging*, *unattached*, etc.
>   are most commonly applied to participles, verbless phrases can also be
>   misrelated.

The offending misrelation in your sentence is a prepositional phrase whose complement is the noun *writer*. The reader will expect *writer* to be the antecedent of the pronoun which follows it as the subject of the main clause: *this*. But *this* refers to the valuable chart and is hence misrelated to *writer*, causing momentary ambiguity.

Steven Pinker in his recent style guide *The Sense of Style* (2014) has some good advice on this issue under the heading *dangling modifiers* (p208-211). He writes:

> The rule decrees that the implied subject of the modifier ... must be
>   identical to the overt subject of the main clause. Most copy editors
>   would recast the main clause, supplying it with a subject to which the
>   modifier can be properly fastened.

In your case this would mean recasting the main clause so that its subject is a personal pronoun: I, she, we, etc.

Pinker goes on to state:

> The decision of whether to recast a sentence to align its subject with
>   the subject of the modifier is a matter of judgment, not grammar. A
>   thoughtlessly placed dangler can confuse the reader or slow her down,
>   and occasionally it can lure her into a ludicrous interpretation.
>   Also, even if a dangler is in no danger of being misinterpreted,
>   enough readers have trained themselves to spot danglers that a writer
>   who leaves it incurs the risk of being judged as slovenly. So in
>   formal styles, it's not a bad idea to keep an eye open for them and to
>   correct the obtrusive ones.

Answer (score 1):

The word you're looking for is *dangling*, applied to constructs that are nonsensical when they're applied to the syntactic element that they're associated with.  In

> As a writer, that has proved to be a truly valuable chart.

the introductory phrase has to refer to the subject, which turns out to be the relative pronoun *that*, which has *chart* as its postcedent.  But as you pointed out, charts can't be writers.  The sense is clearly

> As a writer, I found that the chart proved truly valuable.